# Sum aggregation using jest client

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am new in spring boot and elasticsearch. made the connectivity with aws elasticsearch using this reference https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest. the connection is working fine now I am able to perform the operation. I want to create custom repository(basically,want to use aggregation) and use ElasticsearchTemplate, it gives the following error log

Field elasticsearchTemplate in com.example.abcRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'elasticsearchTemplate' not loaded because auto-configuration 'ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration' was excluded

Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' in your configuration.

How will I resolve the issue. Your help will be very appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the solution. we can use JestClient interface and perform the operation. For Ex: @Autowired
                      JestClient client;

Answer (score -1):

Define a bean in your main Application class file like below

```
@Bean
public JestElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(JestClient client) {
    return new JestElasticsearchTemplate(client);
}
```